# I'm getting "SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration" while writing a discord bot

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to write m first discord bot and while coding an embed I get this:

```
SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = "I've hidden it";

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online');
})

const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Map')
    .setImage('Hidden')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Bot by MuffinLover42'),


channel.send(exampleEmbed);

bot.login(token);
```

I'm using node.js and discord.js
What's wrong with it?
I'm using the code provided by discord with a slight modification.

Comment: Avoid using const for non constants.Use let or var instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_initializer_in_const

Answer (score 0):

> const token = 'I've hidden it';

Try escaping the second ` in your declaration. Right now the compiler is seeing

const token = 'I'

with a bunch of garbage after it.

Additionally,

```
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

.setColor('#0099ff')

.setTitle('Map')

.setImage('Hidden')

.setTimestamp()

.setFooter('Bot by MuffinLover42'),
```

should likely be terminated by a semicolon rather than a comma.

Comment: Yh, the I've hidden it is only here, it's just for the purpose of not showing the token publicly, but I changed it

Comment: Now I'm getting this error:
```ReferenceError: channel is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Muffin\Desktop\Bot\index.js:18:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11```
Sry to bother you but how should I define the channel?

Comment: @Tanuk1 you can use `message.channel`